# VScode insiders intellisense

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm using vscode insiders to develop python codes inside docker containers. In vscode, the intellisense seems to work, but it does not when I edit codes inside containers via vscode insiders. How can the intellisense for vscode insiders work?

On Ubuntu18.04, installed with vscode, vscode-insiders, docker, remote-containers.

For example, 
torch.
does not show any suggestion for the following functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect intellisense for PyTorch isn't working locally either. Please try [changing `"python.jediEnabled"` to `false`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3977) to use the language server instead of Jedi which should lead to better completions.

Otherwise using VS Code's remote containers uses the same setup as locally, so it might be differences in paths in your container compared to your local machine.

Comment: Than you for your kind reply, Brett Cannon. I am sorry for my late reply. As you suggested, intellisense have become enabled with that change. 
Thank you very much!